# PhoneGap cannot call method loadurl of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova

I wrote a method to get the addressinfo from a user and then show it on the map on google. This is the method I wrote

```
function doRemoteMapEmployee(e) {
var mapEmployeeAddressLine1 = (EmployeeInfo.at(0).EmployeeAddressLine1 !== null) ? EmployeeInfo.at(0).EmployeeAddressLine1 + ', ' : '', 
mapEmployeeAddressLine2 = (EmployeeInfo.at(0).EmployeeAddressLine2 !== null) ? EmployeeInfo.at(0).EmployeeAddressLine2 + ', ' : '', 
mapEmployeeAddressLine3 = (EmployeeInfo.at(0).EmployeeAddressLine3 !== null) ? EmployeeInfo.at(0).EmployeeAddressLine3 + ', ' : '', 
mapEmployeeAddressCityTown = (EmployeeInfo.at(0).EmployeeAddressCityTown !== null) ? EmployeeInfo.at(0).EmployeeAddressCityTown + ', ' : '', 
mapEmployeeAddressZipPostCode = (EmployeeInfo.at(0).EmployeeAddressZipPostCode !== null) ? EmployeeInfo.at(0).EmployeeAddressZipPostCode : '', 
address = mapEmployeeAddressLine1 + mapEmployeeAddressLine2 + mapEmployeeAddressLine3 + mapEmployeeAddressCityTown + mapEmployeeAddressZipPostCode;
navigator.app.loadUrl("http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=" + address);
}
```

when I run this, it will give me the error cannot call method loadurl of undefined. Now it gives me the same error if I just replace address with an actuall address. Any Idea what could be going wrong here ?

Comment: According to error message, `navigator.app` is undefined.

Comment: Did you make sure you included the cordova.js file in your HTML?

Comment: I just tried checking for `navigator.app` on my PhoneGap app in an iOS simulator and that var is undefined. I haven't seen this used before, do you need to install a plugin to enable the loadUrl functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
window.open("http://maps.google.co.uk/?q=" + address, "_system");
```

Comment: this opens the url on anther tab when run from a browser but as phonegap applications have no tabbing control it simply hides the application view until it's closed

Comment: So would you like this URL to open in a regular browser?

Comment: You could use `window.open` combined with PhoneGap's InAppBrowser, http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Comment: @DawsonLoudon - yes exactly. I want this to open in the browser (or more importantly, if it's a youtube/not an http link I want the proper application to handle it)

Comment: @IanJamieson - nope, that would open the url at the same app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21119721/65724 - finally I found the problem myself (but couldn't remove the bounty)

Answer (score 0):

while phonegap applications are great developed by debugging on browser, there are some areas where this methodolgy fails.
one of them is `navigator.app`, for its device-related nature, it exists only when actually run on a mobile device, on the browser that object is simply undefined.

when I had to have many iterations of coding/device/debuuging I had to quit the browser methodology and used [genymotion emulator](https://cloud.genymotion.com/), it's a wrapper around [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/%E2%80%8E) that reduced for me the length of coding/result cycle from about 5 minutes to about 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the inAppBrowser plugin:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

You can install this by running:

```
phonegap local add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Then when you run window.open, your page will open within the app in a new browser window which can be closed within your app.

Comment: I don't want my app to handle this on another window, I want my window to stay open and the other url to be opened by the browser (and more importantly - by the appropriate application if the browser is not the one for example when the url is an `app://` one)